# Add two times to get total microsecond

Tags: php

I want to add two dates and want total microsecond. Please tell me another way how to add it. I am adding timestramp and showing total. Please suggest me something. I have no idea and i found in google but didn't get anything. I need microsecond.

```
<?php
$st="2012-11-05 01:23:03";
$et="2012-11-07 05:23:04";

$totalMicroscond= $st+$et;

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$total = strtotime($st) + strtotime($et);
```

Comment: $totalMicroscond= strtotime($st) + strtotime($et); I added but i need microsecond only

Comment: Your question doesn't mention that. `strtotime` function will convert your YYYY-MM-DD date to a timestamp. Isn't that what you need?

Comment: Sorry for that but i added explanation below. I want to add two dates and wants their total microsecond only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a logical reason for adding these two dates, so I assume you want to calculate the difference between the dates.

```
<?php
$st="2012-11-05 01:23:03";
$et="2012-11-07 05:23:04";

$totalMicroscond= (strtotime($et)- strtotime($st))*1000;
echo $totalMicroscond;

?>
```

Comment: Actually i want their total microsecond after adding $s and $et. Is subtraction or addition a correct way to get total microseconds.

Comment: <?php
$time =microtime(true); //but i want to put variable $st in microtime(true).how can i add variable.  
$micro_time=sprintf("%06d",($time - floor($time)) * 1000000);
$date=new DateTime( date('Y-m-d H:i:s.'.$micro_time,$time) );
print "Date with microseconds :<br> "
.$date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s.u");
?>